# How to make an object stay relative to another object

Tags: matrix, vector, gameobject, orientation

In the following example there is a guy and a boat. They have both a position, orientation and velocity.

[image]

The guy is standing on the shore and would like to board. He changes his position so he is now standing on the boat.

[image]

The boat changes velocity and orientation and heads off. **My character however has a velocity of 0,0,0** but I would like him to stay onboard. When I move my character around, I would like to move as if the boat was the ground I was standing on.

[image]

**How do keep my character aligned properly with the boat?** It is exactly like in World Of Warcraft, when you board a boat or zeppelin.

This is my physics code for the guy and boat:

```
this.velocity.addSelf(acceleration.multiplyScalar(dTime));

this.position.addSelf(this.velocity.clone().multiplyScalar(dTime));
```

The guy already has a reference to the boat he's standing on, and thus knows the boat's position, velocity, orientation (even matrices or quaternions can be used).

Comment: Some of the answers to [this similar question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37692/keeping-rotation-between-two-objects/) may help a little with the rotation aspect of this

Comment: Is this being driven by a physics engine? That's the part I'm unsure about, because otherwise it would be simple to solve using a scene graph. All you would have to do was add the character as a child to the boat node when they first establish contact. Conversely, once the character left the boat, all you would have to do was detach him from the boat node and re-add him to the root node of the hierarchy. Parenting and keeping the relations between nodes is already an integral part of the scene graph.

Comment: What have you tried? You're essentially just going to apply the of the boat transforms to the character too. Then apply the rotations of the character in that reference.

Comment: @David Gouveia Unfortunately I can't use a physics engine (use WebGL)

Comment: @Nick You misunderstood. If you were using a physics engine it might be more difficult to implement a scene graph. If you're not using one, then it should be be a good solution. I've googled for "WebGL scenegraph" and found a few ready solutions. Give them a try. Basically what you want in the end is a system where you can simply do `boat.children.add(character)` and everything else works automatically.

Comment: @Nick Well, I have written something about this topic before, which you can find [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/23039/11686) but it's for XNA. It does what you're asking for though - the turret is attached to the tank in my example exactly in the same way that you would like to attach the character to the boat. It's up to you whether to try to distill and adapt that to your needs, or use some helper library :P

Comment: @DavidGouveia Just noticed that my library (THREE.JS) has this parent/children thing which I can use for the transformations :D Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Nick Oh, that's great! Did you manage to get it working already? :)

Comment: @DavidGouveia Yeah, just got translations and rotations working fine when my character is on another object! The only thing remaining is to fix the annoying "shaking" of my character that happens when the parent object is moving... I think it has something to do with the order in which I update the matrices of the objects in my scene, but I still got to investigate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best luck is to learn some matrix math.

You should have some kind of scene graph that establishes the character as a child node of the boat. It then would store it's position relative to the boat.

The boat would have a transformation matrix, you apply that to the child nodes, and the child nodes could stack some more transformations on the matrix letting you move around the boat while moving relative to it.